# Excel : count text occurrences in function of text in 1st colum

Tags: excel

I've been looking for quite some time now... for a way to count text occurrences in a table in function of other text mentions (first column).

So far, COUNTIF/COUNTIF/IF not working  and I have a high number of column so  Pivot table doesn't give me anything usable.

Here's a simplified example of what i'm trying to do:

[image: exemple]

Copiable example data

```
A|Car |Foot|Bike|
-+----+----+-----
B|Car |Bike|Car |
-+----+----+-----
A|Bike|Car |Car |
```

Expected Results

```
 |Car |Foot|Bike|
-+----+----+-----
A|3   |1   |2   |
-+----+----+-----
B|2   |0   |1   |
```

I would like to find a formula that enables to count how many times we have "car" "foot" in function of A, B  as above without a pivot table .

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: What do you mean by "in function of A,B"?

Answer (score 2):

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

using the above layout for the column and row referencing, the following formula was placed in G2 and copied down and to the right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F2=$A$1:$A$3)*($B$1:$D$3=G$1))
```

an alternate more long winded formula you could use is:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$3,$F2,$B$1:$B$3,G$1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$3,$F2,$C$1:$C$3,G$1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$3,$F2,$D$1:$D$3,G$1)
```

Basically you need a COUNTIF statement for each column minus the A/B column.  Since you said you had a lot of columns I left this as an alternative.

Comment: just a note, this is potentially a very processor intense formula if you have a lot of rows.  Definitely don't use whole column references for your ranges...

Comment: @ScottCraner Why does this not work as an array formula? `{=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$3,$F2,INDEX($B$1:$D$3,0,{1,2,3}),G$1))}`

Comment: You can't use a disjointed range array inside the countifs()

Comment: @ScottCraner Disjointed range?  is there another way to do the repetitive column condition in an array instead of doing a sum of individual countifs?

Comment: Outside of an array formula? Not that I am aware.

Comment: The issue is that you actually create an array, not three range references, and COUNTIFS can only use ranges. You could use: `=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$3,$F2,OFFSET($B$1:$B$3,0,{0,1,2}),G$1))` which doesn't need array-entering.

Comment: @Rory I was trying to use index to avoid the volatile nature of offset but thanks for the clarification on the index issue.  Based on OP stating there a lots of columns, I did not think offset was a wise choice to be repeatedly entering.

Comment: I assumed this was purely theoretical as the SUMPRODUCT is easier and simpler. I don't *think* you will get INDEX to play with COUNTIFS here.

Comment: @Rory I did not think of OFFSET().  Thanks, learnt me something new today.

Comment: @Rory I don't think so either.  I was just looking at alternatives, and I thought index would have been a cool way to do it while avoiding offset...alas I was wrong there.

Comment: @ScottCraner  This is all your fault!  "almost always use index over offset" you say!  8) Tee Hee

Comment: I did not say use it, The Sumproduct() formula is better.  I just stated it was a good use of the OFFSET().  Which it is **IF** they wanted to avoid the array formula **AND** the number of formulas used is not excessive.  It comes down to weighing what you want with the calc times required.  Both methods have their draw backs, so it is dealers choice in this instance.

Comment: What you can do though, since the criteria are also ranges, is reverse the order: `=SUM(COUNTIFS($F2,$A$1:$A$3,G$1,INDEX($B$1:$D$3,N(IF(1,ROW($B$1:$D$3))),N(IF(1,{1,2,3})))))` This does need array entry.